# How do I query IMDb for movies that two actors have in common?

Tags: imdb

So I know that John Wayne and James Stewart were both in *The Man Who Shot Liberty Valance* and *The Shootist*. How do I use IMDb to find other movies that they were both in?

Conversely, was anyone else besides those two actors in both of those movies? Can I search for actors that two movies have in common?

It's not at all obvious whether or not either is possible, despite the "database" portion of the site's name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Short version: [here it is!](http://www.imdb.com/search/common)

Long version: First go to "Advanced Search", which isn't even linked from the main page; it's an option in the search dropdown:

> [image: advanced search at the bottom of the search dropdown]

There is a link called "Collaborations and Overlaps":

> [image: third option, link at the end of the paragraph]

That takes you to [this nifty search page](http://www.imdb.com/search/common), where both searches are possible.

(The answers are "*How the West Was Won*" and "John Carradine, Chuck Roberson, and Ralph Volkie", by the way.)